# Wrong Relationship Type when adding Contacts to Organization

Tags: relationships, contact-types

when adding **Contacts to Organization**, I have the pop-up menu showing the wrong **Relationship Type**.
This happens after selecting some Organization that need to be linked to another Organization.
I have a dedicated Relationship Type for my need. It is set for Organizations only, but that precise Relationship Type doesn't appear in the list.
What could block the list to show all the available Relationship Type ?

Another symptom is shown here. I have selected in this exemple 3 Organizations. The list offers relations that are made for Individual (Volunteer for, Employee of…
[image]

Comment: Do either of the contacts have contact subtypes?  Does the relationship type apply only to contact subtypes?

Comment: Hello Jon, none of the contacts (Organization in this pattern) have contact subtypes.

Comment: They are basic organizations that need to be liked to another organization. The needed relationship is made for all organizations. What is odd the relation "Employee of" is in the list.

Comment: Can you clarify how you get to that screen. I don't recognise it. I expect the system to show me the Relationship Types before I select the Contacts.

Comment: TO make it easier to follow your answer pls provide links to the https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org site

Comment: @petednz-fuzion Here is the link to the page : https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/group/search?_qf_AddToOrganization_display=true&qfKey=d0854a7063bbc3dcb6ca7cfd7e74cb8a_6482 In this case, the system shows me the available Relationship Types after the selections of the Contacts. You can see that in this case, I selected 3 contacts before choosing a relation.

Comment: sorry but that link does not work.  if you want me to understand can you pls add some more screenshots or steps to your Q so i can replicate